# Aerospike set expiration date for specific field

Tags: caching, redis, aerospike, aerospike-ce, aerospike-loader

I have an Aerospike cache consists of list of data with value of json like structure.

example value: `{"name": "John", "count": 10}`

I was wandering if it is possible to set an expiration time for only the count field and reset it after some time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aerospike doesn't support such functionality out of the box. You would have to code this (hence your other post I guess:
[Best way to update single field in Aerospike](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73282994/best-way-to-update-single-field-in-aerospike/73284978#73284978)). You can add filters to only do this based on metadata of the record (the last update time of the record, accessible through Expressions) or any other logic and it should be super efficient and performant to then let a background ops query do the work.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach can be adding your own custom expiration time stamp in your bin data like so:
`{"name":"John", "count":10, "validTill":1672563600000000000}`.

Here, I am using as below (you can use a different future timestamp format):

```
$ date --date="2023-01-01 09:00:00" +%s%N
1672563600000000000
```

Now when you read the record, read through an expression that returns *count* = 10 if your current clock is behind *validTill*, 0 otherwise. This can work if the *count* value on read is all you care about.  Also, when you go to update the count value in a future write, you can use the same expression logic to update both *count* and *validTill*.

If this works for you, you don't have to scan and update records using background jobs.